# Структура state. Redux

Tags: javascript, redux

Делаю учебный проект на react/redux. Есть вот такая структура стэйта:

```
const defaultState = {
  calcState: {
    currentDate: '',
    currentMoney: '',
    dataList: [],
  },
};
```

Пытаюсь сделать редьюсер для полей currentDate и currentMoney.

```
const calcReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case CALC_CHANGE_DATE_TEXT: {
      const { date } = action.payload;
      return { ...state, calcState: { currentDate: date } };
    }

    case CALC_CHANGE_MONEY_TEXT: {
      const { money } = action.payload;
      return { ...state, calcState: { currentMoney: money } };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
```

Получается в case'ах я возвращаю старый state, но с новым полем calcState, в котором хранится всего одно поле currentDate/currentMoney. А как сделать, чтобы возвращался старый state, со всеми старыми полями, но с добавлением изменений?

Comment: { ...state, calcState: { ...state.calcState,  currentDate: date } };

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!

Comment: и Вам не нужно так напрягаться и каждый раз через деструктуризацию создавать переменную из `payload`.
для этого можно сразу применить деструктуризацию на `action`, например так: `const calcReducer = (state = defaultState, { type, payload }) => {`. теперь у вас сразу есть 2 доступные переменные в редьюсере - `type` и `payload`

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
return { ...state, calcState: { ...state.calcState, currentDate: date } };
...
return { ...state, calcState: { ...state.calcState, currentMoney: money } };
```